# Missing Android Virtual Device Manager options

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-virtual-device

I'll go straight to the point.

Reference picture:

[image]

The problem I'm having:

[image]

As you can see, I am missing the other options. How can I get internal storage, SD Card, and Emulator Options to pop up for my AVD?

Comment: If you are new then try to use Android Studio. Because in later version of android adt bundle has some these kind of problem & Google is suggesting to use Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I would just trash the Android Emulator and go with [Genymotion Emulator](http://www.genymotion.com/) which is the fastest Android emulator and completely free for personal use.

You will thank me a bunch when you start using it.

Hope this helps. Happy emulating :)

P.S. Please mark this answer as correct if it helps